# Spring Security - pages redirect to login even if authentication successfull on Explorer and Safari

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, safari

I'm working on a web-app Spring MVC with Spring Security for the authentication.

Everything works fine except on Explorer and Safari. When I log in successfully I can access at one page and when I want to access another page, the browser ask me to log again... I have tested the application on Chrome and Firefox and everything is OK...

My spring-security.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">  

    <security:http auto-config="true">  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_USER" />  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/acc*" access="ROLE_USER" />  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/compte/**" access="ROLE_USER" />  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/aide/**" access="ROLE_USER" />  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/clients/**" access="ROLE_USER" />  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/employes/get.html*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/employes/**" access="ROLE_MONITRICE" />  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/reunions/**" access="ROLE_USER" />  
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/accueil.html" authentication-failure-url="/fail2login.html" />  
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout.html" />  
    </security:http>  

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">  
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="employeDao">
            <security:password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>  

</beans>
```

My spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/database.properties" />  
    <context:component-scan base-package="ch.tupperware.tuppergestion" />  

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/> 

    <!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">  
     <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>  
     <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>  
     <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>  
     <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="mapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper">
      <property name="mappingFiles">
        <list>
          <value>dozerMapping.xml</value>              
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean> 


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AmbassadriceEntity</value>
                <value>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AbstractEmployeEntity</value>
                <value>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AbstractClientEntity</value>
                <value>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AutreClientEntity</value>
                <value>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.ConseillereEntity</value>
                <value>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.HotesseEntity</value>
                <value>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.InviteEntity</value>
                <value>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.MonitriceEntity</value>
                <value>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.ReunionEntity</value>
                <value>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.ClientReunionEntity</value>
                <value>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.RoleEntity</value>
                <value>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AdministrateurEntity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

  <bean id="employeeDao" class="ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.dao.EmployeDaoImpl"></bean>

  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" id="hibernateTransactionManager">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>  
  </bean>  

  <bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />

  <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
      <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.errors.RessourceNotAuthorizedException">
                errors/403
            </prop>
        </props>
      </property>
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

And my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>tuppergestion</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/tupper-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>tuppergestion</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/errors/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>   

    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/errors/403.jsp</location>
    </error-page>   

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/errors/genericException.jsp</location>
    </error-page>   

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>  
        <listener-class>  
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener  
        </listener-class>  
    </listener>  

    <context-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value>/WEB-INF/tupper-*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>    

<!-- Spring Security -->  
    <filter>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>  
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy  
        </filter-class>  
    </filter>  

    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>   

</web-app>
```

My Spring version is 3.2.5.RELEASE

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

I've found that my problem occurs when I use an address with a redirection.
My site www.xxxx.com redirect on xxx.synology.me 
When I try to connect direct on xxx.synology.me I have not any problems on Safari.
Is there something specific to do with the cross-domaine cookies?

Comment: In debugger, can you check the cookies? Login first, and check before you hit any other URL. I feel that they are not being retained, and therefore the session is not available.

Comment: You are right! I have somme cookies (JSESSIONID) in Chrome that I don't have in Safari... How can I resolve this?

Comment: When you login in IE/Safari, do you see JSESSIONID?
Also check if cookies are enabled on both the browsers.

Comment: No I don't see JSESSIONID. I can see cookies from other sites so I think my cookies are enables.

Comment: Is "xxx.synology.me" inside your context? or is it an external website?